# How do I host files on my drupal 7 site

Tags: file, upload, drupal-7, host

I need to upload some files (adobe illustrator files) and post download links on a drupal 7 website.  I have an admin account to the drupal interface, but currently don't have ftp access to the server where the site is hosted.

Is there some way to upload the files to the site through the drupal interface? This would be ideal.  I just need to upload them and have links to where they are on the server so I can create a page with these links on it.

Is this something I need ftp access to do?  It would take a few days to get ftp access... but If I do need ftp access, where in the drupal file structure should the files be placed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install the IMCE module http://drupal.org/project/imce. It gives you a file browser of the 'files' directory on the web server. Install and activate it, then you'll have the browser as a tab on your profile.

Comment: If a module is needed, I'll have to have ftp access. I'll give that a try once I get ftp access to the server.

the only "files" directory I found was "sites/default/files".  is that where I should upload files if I choose to do so manually?  Just want to make sure i'm putting files in an ok, upgrade-safe location.

Comment: Yes, that is the right place to put your files. If the account you are logged in on has sufficient permissions, you should be able to upload a module via the web interface and not have to use ftp. Just go to Modules, click on Install new module at the top of the page and upload the zipped module.